# How can I print the string value and not the hex in GDB debugger?

Tags: gdb, debugging

```
(gdb) run hello
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /Users/doug/langs/c/test hello

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0xbffffa7c) at hw3b.c:14
14     if (argc != 2) {
(gdb) printf "%s", argv
??????(gdb)
```

I searched other questions on SO and I tried all the commands that I found but I keep getting ??? marks. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv` isn't a string, it's a `char**` - a pointer to the first of possibly multiple C strings.

I think you're looking for:

```
print argv[0]
print argv[1]
...
```

Or if you want to use printf:

```
printf "%s\n", argv[0]
```

But there's really no reason to in such a simple case, since gdb does know how to print `char*` strings.

Or, if you want to be fancy, this works:

```
print *argv@argc
```

The syntax `FOO@NUM` tells it to print an array of `NUM` elements starting at `FOO`. And I have no idea why the dereferencing works, but it does - I guess gdb is just nice like that. Someone enlighten me?